# Git merge renamed files as new files

Tags: git

I have a repo like this (numbers are sequence of commits):

```
 1 -- 2 -- 5 [master]
       \
        3 -- 4  [feature]
```

In 1 I have files `tool.txt` and `code.txt`.
In 3, both files were modified, but `code.txt` is a totally different thing from the old `code.txt`, it is in fact a new file.

In 4, `code.txt` is renamed `alternative_code.txt`.

I would like to merge the changes of `feature` into `master`, but `alternate_code.txt` should not replace `code.txt` in the merge, but be added as a new file. If I do a regular merge, the alternate code will replace the master's code.

In reality, I have a certain number of files that were handled like `code.txt` (replaced and then renamed).

Is there a practical way to merge the branch into master, without "backtracking" the rename and add the renamed files as new files, instead of trying to merge them?

If the file was not renamed, I want to do a regular merge.

Is this possible (e.g. by using a specific merge policy)?

EDIT

To clarify, after the merge `master` should have 3 files:

- `tool.txt`, merged from master and feature
- `code.txt`, the file that was in 5
- `alternate_code.txt`, the file that was in 4

Comment: Thanks, I will read around and see if it works as I meant.